# What is the optimal way of using a Mac with an ultrawide screen?

Tags: display

I have an ultrawide screen (similar [to this](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B01BV1Q0L4)), which is connected to my Mac. I am looking for a way to split this screen into two or three virtual screens when needed, for easy multitasking. OSX does support screen splitting if you hold on the green button at the top of any screen, but it's very inconvenient because it takes a lot of clicks to switch which applications are currently displayed.

Is there a better way to make efficient use of such a big screen?

Comment: Have you considered some type of snap to screen utility from the Mac App Store that would snap windows to locations similar to dragging them to the top or sides in Windows?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Been there before...

**Currently**, there is no way in MacOS to achieve true multi-monitor support on one display. I have a wide LG and the way I get around this is to us 
 keyboard shortcuts to define sections of the screen with snap tools such as:

- [BetterSnapTool](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/bettersnaptool/id417375580?mt=12)
- [Moom](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/moom/id419330170?mt=12)